# Putting common command button code in ThisWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

After moving command button code into the ThisWorkbook area as opposed to the individual sheet it doesn't appear to get called.  Is there a reason for this, is there some way I can have the same code called from multiple buttons each on different worksheets?

Comment: You can call a Sub nested in a module from multiple controles, from any sheets. I suggest you read about Private Sub vs Public Sub while you're at it.

Comment: @TheNotSoGuru gives a good example.  For a more specific solution could we see your code?  It'll pretty much be a case of placing it in a standard module and calling it from each of your buttons, but there could be code references that fail if it's moved (ranges pointing to the wrong sheet, use of the `Me` keyword for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command button is a worksheet object, not a workbook object.

With this being said, you can reuse the code by keeping the command button in your worksheet's object, but place the main code in a **standard module** (keep it away from your workbook's module).

> - This would be in a standard module:

```
Sub mainCode(ws As Worksheet)

    'Your Code

End Sub
```

> - This would be in your Worksheet's private module:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    mainCode ws   'make a call to the code above

End Sub
```

Comment: Very helpful thanks TheNotSoGuru.  In my case the fault was that I was using an ActiveX button, which searches only in the worksheet object for it's click procedure.  Changed that to a Form button and I was able to select the appropriate macro from a list.